# Why is my thinmusic server failing to start as a service on Ubuntu Linux even though it runs manually?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, react-scripts, nodejs-server

I have a Linux Ubunut 22.04 Server at IONOS.
I want to develop and deploy a [thinmusic server](https://github.com/anantn/thinmusic).

I installed NodeJS, npm, react-script. The server is running when I call it manually.
But when I want to start it as a service, it doesn't work.

Please support me.

I have a thinmusic.service:

```
[Unit]
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/npm start
Restart=on-failure
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/vhosts/playlist-manager.de/script.playlist-manager.de/vendor/thinmusic/
Environment=REACT_APP_MUSICKIT_TOKEN=...
Environment=REACT_APP_FIREBASE_TOKEN=...

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Following error occurs:

```
× thinmusic.service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/thinmusic.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-06-05 05:18:48 UTC; 1s ago
    Process: 460619 ExecStart=/usr/bin/npm start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 460619 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 33ms

Jun 05 05:18:48 focused-khorana.217-160-89-20.plesk.page systemd[1]: thinmusic.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jun 05 05:18:48 focused-khorana.217-160-89-20.plesk.page systemd[1]: Stopped thinmusic.service.
Jun 05 05:18:48 focused-khorana.217-160-89-20.plesk.page systemd[1]: thinmusic.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 05 05:18:48 focused-khorana.217-160-89-20.plesk.page systemd[1]: thinmusic.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 05 05:18:48 focused-khorana.217-160-89-20.plesk.page systemd[1]: Failed to start thinmusic.service.
```

I want to start it everytime with the server as a service.